# Dynamic return values based on user

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Am looking for a way to use authentication as a key (certificate) to determine which return values are exposed by a service operation.

For example;
- presume the underlying source has 5 columns that can be returned, 1 - 5
- Authenticated user A invokes Operation 'GetData' and user B invokes 'GetData'

I would like to enable User A to receive columns 1,2,3 and user B columns 1,4,5

Why is this important?

For privacy reasons, we are required to return only the data that a consumer needs to see, not all the data. The alternative to what I am asking is to create one operation for each consumer.

Many thanks for your thoughts.